# CSharp . NET to Java Array dimension declaration initialization

Tags: java, c#, .net, multidimensional-array

I want to translate this expression from .NET to Java.

**.NET**

```
public Double Imaginary {
  get {
    return m_imaginary;
  }
}

private static Complex[,][] complexRotation = new Complex[maxBits, 2][];

complexRotation[numberOfBits - 1, directionIndex] = rotation;
```

My **Java** Translation.

```
public Double Imaginary() {
  return m_imaginary;
}
```

But this expression I don't understand, how to do it.

```
private static final Complex[,][] complexRotation = new Complex[maxBits, 2][];


complexRotation[numberOfBits - 1, directionIndex] = rotation;
```

Please tell me about this:

Comment: I want to know, what is the bad in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is not available in Java, but you can do it just like this:

```
private static final Number[][][] complexRotation = new Number[maxBits][2][];
```

`complexRotation[numberOfBits - 1][directionIndex] = rotation;`

I hope it is helpful!

Lukas

Answer (score 0):

In .NET `[,]` signifies a two-dimensional array.

Java doesn't have multidimensional arrays. You can either use a one-dimensional array and some math to index into it to simulate one (this is what .NET does on the inside anyways), or an array of arrays.